# Will Ubuntu work on my ASUS q406da br5t6 laptop? (2 in 1)

Tags: touchpad, laptop, asus, touchscreen, tablet

For the  ASUS q406da br5t6 (which seems to be very very similar hardware to an ASUS Zenbook).

I've been trying various Linux distro live images to see what support they have for this laptop, including Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04
What I've noticed has been that there's no support for auto-switching to tablet mode (actually I saw no support for switching to a tablet mode at all?) when pulling the screen back, which would do things like disabling the keyboard and touchpad, rotating the screen, etc.

What are the chances that I'm doing something wrong and/or this is a limitation in the live image only?
I've seen other people say that it 'should work ootb' but some times they're not considering the tablet portion of it, which is a big part of why I want to use this model.

I appreciate any pointers even if you don't have the exact answer. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to follow up on this after some digging.
It appears that the issue with rotation (and likely the lid sensor) is a missing driver issue.
I found this:
https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/amd-gfx/2019-May/034431.html

So it looks like for right now, the rotation function won't work. But hopefully in the near future!
Probably likewise for the lid being folded back (for auto-tablet)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need to do some configuration to get it to work but it should be fine in the end: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen

Although, there is a thread detailing some issues with touchscreen devices and Ubuntu 18.04: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2396712

I can't find any examples with your exact model so you might have to just give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: The touch screen itself seemed to work fine on Ubuntu 18.04. It even popped up the on-screen keyboard.
But it did not automatically disable the keyboard/touchpad when I folded the computer, and it did not reorient the screen when I turned it around.